# Only "Fragment + View Model" in Android Studio JetPack version 3.2 Preview Beta 5

Tags: android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-studio-3.2

I am checking lots of tutorials on Youtube and Google and all are referring to snapshots where the default activity to be selected for JetPack is " Activity & Fragment + ViewModel". However when i create a new activity i see the following screen:

[image]
New Activity Creation Screen in Android Studio 3.2 Beta 5

As you can see, I can only see the option "Fragment + View Model" while creating new activity. 
Can anybody confirm is this is the latest screen or am I missing something in Android Studio.

I ran all the updates for the latest Android Studio 3.2 Preview Beta 5.

Answer (score 0):

The option is not included in Android Studio 3.2 RC 1.

Here's my versioning information:

```
    Android Studio 3.2 RC 2
    Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.4974118, built on August 23, 2018
    JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
    JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
    Windows 10 10.0
```

Comment: Hi Michael, 
I am also using the same version of android, but still i am getting Fragment + Viewmodel only. 
Android Studio 3.2 RC 2
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.4974118, built on August 24, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.6

Comment: yes this is not in the RC , i found it in the Cannery channel